# Is it possible to use fee publisher to create an event with attendees?

Tags: event, chatter-feed, publisher, publisher-action

Is it possible to use feed publisher to create an event with attendees?
Users do a lot from the publisher on an Account page, but they'd like to do this to. 
Understand this is changing from a 1 object creation to a 1+ many object creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this declaratively with the standard Create quick action -- those can only create a single record (the Event record), not add the attendees.

You should be able to do this programmatically with a custom Visualforce quick action. Because you're writing the action UI from scratch (and a controller), you could create a form allowing the user to add multiple child rows and create the event and attendees at the same time, using [EventRelation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm) to add the attendees. Check out the Custom Quick Actions section of the [Salesforce Quick Actions Implementation Guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/actions_impl_guide.pdf).